# How to set DateAxis TickUnit (Date Interval) in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, charts

I'm developing a chart using JavaFX. I needed `DateAxis`, so I use
`DateAxis` from [this code](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=Corendon-master/src/nl/itopia/corendon/components/DateAxis.java). The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU2bH.jpg). But I want show 2 date
interval, I didn't find solution. The result always show one day interval. This is my code.

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>> series = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Date, Number>> series1Data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    series1Data.add(new XYChart.Data<Date, Number>(new GregorianCalendar(2018,1, 12).getTime(), 2));
    series1Data.add(new XYChart.Data<Date, Number>(new GregorianCalendar(2018, 1, 15).getTime(), 3));

    series1Data.add(new XYChart.Data<Date, Number>(new GregorianCalendar(2018, 1, 16).getTime(), 4));


    series.add(new XYChart.Series<>("Series1", series1Data));

    NumberAxis numberAxis = new NumberAxis();
    DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis();
    dateAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    dateAxis.setLowerBound(new GregorianCalendar(2018,2, 12).getTime());
    dateAxis.setUpperBound(new GregorianCalendar(2018,2, 16).getTime());
    dateAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Date>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Date object) {
            return simpleDateFormat.format(object);
        }
        @Override
        public Date fromString(String string) {
            return null;
        }
    });

    LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(dateAxis, numberAxis, series);
    Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 900, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but it seems that `DateAxis` API does not allow you to specify a preferred displayed interval, so you need to change it yourself.

In `DateAxis` class there's an `Interval` enum. If you change this line:

```
DAY(Calendar.DATE, 1),
```

To this one:

```
DAY(Calendar.DATE, 2),
```

And comment other intervals as necessary...

```
//        HOUR_12(Calendar.HOUR, 12),
```

2-day intervals will be shown. Keep in mind that doing this is contrary to the author's intent, who wrote it this way so that the intervals are adjusted automatically, and it's a very crude solution. For a better one, you'd have to rewrite the `calculateTickValues` method, as well as change the private enum to some kind of public API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !